# Capturing the text of the closest span element with a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to fetch the text of a span that has a given class -> closest to the click via Google Tag Manager. Is it possible via plain JS or JQuery?

The code looks like this:

```
<a class="contenttile" href="/mypage" style="height: 193px;">
  <div class="imageContainer" style="height: 97px;">
    <img src="http://http:someadress.com/foto.jpg" class="blurr" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="textContainer">
    <span class="text3">My text</span>
    <br>
  </div>
</a>
```

What I want to return via a function is `My text`.

---

I was trying different snippets found here, but since im a JS lame I couldn't adjust it to work properly.

For example this one:

```
function(){
  var ec = {{Click Element}};
  var x = $(ec).closest('span');
  return x.innerText;
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error? is ec a jQuery click event?

Comment: .closest() searches up the dom tree ( parents, grandparents etc ) . if you want to look inside the `a` clicked tag use `ec.find("span.text-3").text()`

Comment: What are you clicking on, there are no children of text3 so closest is not going to work

Comment: im clicking on the image, because it works when someone clicks on the span (text)

Answer (score 0):

since you are using jQuery

```
return ec.find('.text3').text();
```

Comment: Doesent work, dont forget i want to use the {{Click Element}} native variable to catch the closest span to the click, a user performed.

Comment: have you tried find('span'). closest is looking for parents. find is used to search for childs

Answer (score 0):

In GTM, your click may register two events: gtm.click and gtm.linkClick. Depending on which one your tag is set to fire on (ie. you can set it to fire on all clicks or just links), then you could use either of the following:

1. If using just links, then `$(ce).find('.textContainer').find('span').text()`
2. If using all clicks, then `$(ce).closest('span').text()`

Comment: So the whole code should be:

`function(){
  var ce = {{Click Element}};
  var x = $(ce).closest('span').text();
  return x
}`

?

Comment: Basically yes, that's the correct logic, maybe add in checks here and there, wrap it in try/catch, etc...